# how to set focus for label when click the any button using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have one asp:Textbox and one asp:label control in my aspx page. I want to set focus for label when clicking the button using javascript. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Many thanks...

Comment: It doesn't make sense to focus on a label ... does it? Also, where does the button come from?

Comment: Are you still having problems?

Answer (score 4):

You need to access the element via an id or a class an call [**focus()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.focus):

```
document.getElementById('myTextBox').focus();
```

As Pointy *pointed* out: When you mean by clicking on a label to select the textbox, you just need to set the [**for**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/label) attribute on the label to the ID of the textbox.

```
<label for="myTextBox">Label Text</label>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to just set the "for" attribute of the `<label>` to the "id" of the element?  That's sort-of what labels do.

Comment: htmlfile: Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus

Comment: @Kathirvel well, make sure you're using the control's `ClientID`. If you really want to focus a label, I don't know if it's even possible. Maybe what you really want is the `<label for>` solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` attribute does it for you out of the box

```
<label for="{the id you want}"> </label>
```

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/label)

Because it's asp.net application you need to use the `ClientID`:

```
<label for='<%= myTextBox.ClientID %>'> </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use `.focus()` it will do the focus part
```